# Sample size calculation for non-inferiority prospective observational study with paired nominal data?

Tags: categorical-data, sample-size, paired-data, observational-study, non-inferiority

I'm doing a diagnostic observational study, where doctors in two different fields (emergency physicians vs radiologists) try to diagnose same patient (paired sample). The question we are trying to answer is if emergency physicians are non-inferior to radiologists in dagnosing a specific disease with ultrasound.

The outcomes will be in percentage of accuracy against final diagnosis (true outcome): for instance radiologists diagnosed correctly 85% of the time and emergency physicians 70% of the time.

***The problem I have is how do I calculate how many patients we need for this non-inferiority study with paired nominal/categorical data?***

Found this calculator but not sure if this is the correct one and do not really understand the input values either:
http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Test-1-Proportion/1-Sample-Non-Inferiority-or-Superiority

Have been struggling to find an answer to this question for long, any help would be highly appreciated!

Best regard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the post. Please let me know if there is something unclear and I will clearify.